# bar(1:30) bug in matlab?

Tags: matlab, graph

I have a question regarding, bar(h) in Matlab. It's so easy but so annoying for me.
When we use e.x. bar(1:30) it shows the following figure
[image: bar(1:30)]

I really do not know if I can erase that meaningless space between 30 and 35 in the horizontal axis, or, in other words, keep my shape between 1 and 30.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using? This is not reproducible in R2018a.

Comment: You probably want [`axis tight`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not reproducible in R2018a, so yes, it probably is a bug.

But it's easily fixable with [`xlim`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html):

```
xlim([1, 31])
```

Or [`axis`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html#buk989s-1-style):

```
axis('tight')
```